# how to disabled the onclick function if user did not have access for that function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have user access function that have data like this.
Data read from API

```
  "allowView": true,
  "allowAdd" : true,
  "allowEdit": false,
  "allowDel" : false
```

this is how I check the condition for the data. Condition for user access data.

```
 e.allowView== true ? $("button.viewBtn").prop("disabled",false)  : $("button.viewBtn").prop("disabled",true);
 e.allowAdd== true ? $("button.addBtn").prop("disabled",false)   : $("button.addBtn").prop("disabled",true);
 e.allowEdit== true ? $("button.editBtn").prop("disabled",false)  : $("button.editBtn").prop("disabled",true);
 e.allowDel== true ? $("button.deleteBtn").prop("disabled",false): $("button.deleteBtn").prop("disabled",true);
```

but I have problem to call the class `deleteBtn` in `<span>` because in this line of code did not have button.

```
  <span class="text-center"><a onclick ="deleteMsg('${emsg_id}')" class=""><span class="text-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete"><em class="icon ni ni-trash"></em></span></a></span>
```

How do I add the condition in my user access statement so I can use it in my `<span>` without adding the `<button>` ?

Comment: tell the onclick event function to return false

Comment: Your security check is in the wrong place.  Yes, it *should* (also) be on the button but it's trivial for the user to bypass that.   It needs to be within `deleteMsg` *and* within the server-side version which should then fail (possibly badly).

Comment: Give your `<a onclick` the same class `class='deleteBtn'` and change your selector to just the class `$(".deleteBtn").prop...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can refactor this code so instead of:

```
e.allowView== true ? $("button.viewBtn").prop("disabled",false)  : $("button.viewBtn").prop("disabled",true);
```

Can be just:

```
$("button.viewBtn").prop("disabled", e.allowView != true);
```

And the second thing, you can in your callback function:

```
deleteMsg(par) {
if (!e.allowDel)
return false;

// Your existing code...
}
```

Also you can add some class on your link, so it can add some kind of "disabled" class there...

For example:

```
if (!e.allowDel) $(selectorToLink).addClass('disabled-link');

.disabled-link {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```